# Memory management routine error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use FP routine, but it doesn't work...Why?
This is my code:

```
int output = FindPattern(0x0042A000, 0x2000, "\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x76\x08\x89\x46\x44", "x????xxxxxx"); 
                if (output > -1) { 
                    ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (PVOID)address, &value2, sizeof(value2), NULL);                  
                } 

Function:
int FindPattern(int start_offset, int size, const char * pattern, const char * mask) 
{ 
    int pos = 0; 

    for (int retAddress = start_offset; retAddress < start_offset + size; retAddress++) 
    { 
        if (*(const char*)retAddress == pattern[pos] || mask[pos] == '?') 
        { 
            if (mask[pos+1] == '\0') 
                return retAddress+1; 
            pos++; 
        } 
        else 
            pos = 0; 
    } 

    return -1; 
}
```

I also tried:

```
DWORD output = FindPattern(hProcHandle, "\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x76\x08\x89\x46\x44", "x????xxxxxx");


bool VerifyAddress(HANDLE hwnd, DWORD dwAddress, char *bMask, char *szMask )
{
    PBYTE *pTemp = { 0 };

    for ( int i = 0; *szMask; ++szMask, ++bMask, ++i )
    {

        if ( !ReadProcessMemory( hwnd, reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(dwAddress + i), &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), 0 ) ){
            return false;
        }

        if ( *szMask == 'x' && (char)pTemp != *bMask){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

DWORD FindPattern(HANDLE hwnd, char* bMask, char *szMask )
{
    for ( DWORD dwCurrentAddress = 0x4FFFFFF; dwCurrentAddress < 0x7FFFFFF; dwCurrentAddress++ ){
        if ( VerifyAddress( hwnd, dwCurrentAddress, bMask, szMask )) {
            return dwCurrentAddress;
        }
    }
```

But with these codes I get always

> Unhandled exception at 0x01034BB1 in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x02343DA2.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
int output = FindPattern(0x0042A000, 0x2000,
```

indicates that you are using address 0x0042A000 local to your process, so you are iterating over some random addresses in your process which is Undefined Behaviour and ends with exception.

[ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) copies specified memory from some other process to your process and stores in in memory buffer you provide in this function call as lpBuffer parameter.

Comment: Besides that you mix `int` and `char*`. Use a memsize type when you deal with pointers otherwise it will fail sooner or later. `int val = (int)address` fails because address does not fit in `val` on 64-bit systems.